# Is O(n^(1/logn)) actually constant?

Tags: math, big-o

I came across this time complexity function and according to me, it is actually constant. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
n^(1/logn) => (2^m)^(1/log(2^m)) => (2^m)^(1/m) => 2
```

Since any n can be written as a power of 2, I can do the above simplification and prove that it is constant, right?

Comment: Without writing down a proof, but simply testing some cases. Yes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is simply a math question better asked in math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming `log` is the natural log, then this is equivalent to `e`, not `2`, but either way it's a constant.

First, let:

```
k = n^(1 / log n)
```

Then take the log of both sides:

```
log k = (1 / log n) * log n
```

So:

```
log k = 1
```

Now raise both sides to the power of `e` to get:

```
e^(log k) = e^(1)
```

And thus:

```
k = e.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative proof:

- 1 / (log n) = (log e) / (log n) = log<sub>n</sub> e by the [change of base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) identity.
- Then, n<sup>log<sub>n</sub> e</sup> = e by the definition of the logarithm as the inverse of exponentiation.

Comment: Yes, log e = 1, because exp(1) = e.

Comment: Yeah yeah my bad, sorry. I guess I was thinking about base 2 since that's what the question used. Or maybe it's cause I just got out of bed and am stupid :-)

Comment: No worries. It actually works whatever base you use, just replace e with the base and then the constant at the end equals the base.